# How to write the post request in wso2 api manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

i want to send the POST request with JSON as POST data and it should also accept attachments. I checked the documentation but unable to create the POST

Answer (score 0):

Create a new api with http post type and Payload Parameter name and body parameter type.
if you use form/multipart you must edit some axis2 config file in api manager.
go to wso2am/repository/conf/axis2 and edit axis2.xml.

add this lines:

```
 <messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data"
                      class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>


 <messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data"
                      class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
```